# Issue with displaying the correct output. JS radio button selection and addition

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<input type="radio" id="radiobtn1" name="bubbles" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> Less Than 10 Bubbles<br />
<input type="radio" id="radiobtn2" name="bubbles" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> 10 Bubbles<br />
<input type="radio" id="radiobtn3" name="bubbles" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> More than 10 Bubbles<br />


<br />
<input type="radio" id="radiobtn4" name="hours" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> 1 Hour<br />
<input type="radio" id="radiobtn5" name="hours" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> 2 Hours<br />
<input type="radio" id="radiobtn6" name="hours" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> Any Longer<br />


<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="radiobtn7" name="bubbles" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> Inflatable Goals<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="radiobtn8" name="bubbles" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> Icey Cold Bottled Water<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="radiobtn9" name="bubbles" onclick="CalculatePrice();"> Photo and Video Package<br />

<script>
function CalculatePrice() {
  var a, b;
  var c = 0;
  var d = 0;
  var e = 0;
  var price;

     if($(radiobtn1).is(':checked')) {
        a = 0;
         // alert(a);
     }
     else if($(radiobtn2).is(':checked')) {
        a = 1;
          //alert(a);
     }
     else if($(radiobtn3).is(':checked')) {
        a = 0;
          //alert(a);
     }


     if($(radiobtn4).is(':checked')) {
        b = 350;
          //alert(b);
     }
     else if($(radiobtn5).is(':checked')) {
        b = 450;
          //alert(b);
     }
     else if($ (radiobtn6).is(':checked')) {
        b = 0;
         // alert(b);
     }

        if($(radiobtn7).is(':checked')) {
        c = 50;
          //alert(b);
     }
     else if($(radiobtn8).is(':checked')) {
        d = 20;
          //alert(b);
     }
     else if($ (radiobtn9).is(':checked')) {
        e = 50;
         // alert(b);
     }


    if(a == 0)
      {
        price = 0;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Contact Us For Pricing.";
        //alert(price);
      }
         else if (b == 0)
           {
             price = 0;
            // alert(price);
           }
                else
                  {
                    price = b;
                    price = price + new Number(c) + new Number(d) + new Number(e);

                            if(price != undefined)
                            {
                                price = "$" + price;
                                    //document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '$';
                                    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = price;
                            }
                            else if(a == 0)
                            {
                                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Contact Us For Pricing.";
                            }
                  }

}
</script>

<br /><br />
<div id="output" style="font-weight:normal;color:#000000;letter-spacing:0pt;word-spacing:-2pt;font-size:36px;text-align:left;font-family:helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:1;"></div>
```

I am having trouble with the output of `CalculatePrice()` displaying $NaN or not adding the checkboxes. I have looked over it many times and still can't seem to work out what the issue is. I have all the checkboxes being added if they were selected but it only seems to add 1 and then not the rest. Not sure what to do!

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to DO?

Comment: @meni181818 It's clear if you run the script. I just need the selections to affect the price that is displayed in the bottom `div`. The check boxes are meant to add a certain number to the total `price` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What is the variable `radiobtn1` and so on?

Comment: @epascarello It's checking which radio button is selected. This will then affect the price.

Comment: No, you never defined the variable. What you are doing is very bad practice. You should not just reference an element by its id. Use the id selector.

Comment: @epascarello Ahh okay thank you. What do you mean by using the id selector?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Change code similar to `$(radiobtn1)` to `$("#radiobtn1")`.  You're referencing an id, and that's the syntax you use to do so.
2. Instead of calling the function from within the html, call it from the JS using jQuery's `.change()` function.

### jQuery

```
$('input').change(function(){
    CalculatePrice();
});


function CalculatePrice() {
    var a, b;
    var c = 0;
    var d = 0;
    var e = 0;
    var price;

    if ($("#radiobtn1").is(':checked')) {
        a = 0;
        //alert(a);
    } else if ($("#radiobtn2").is(':checked')) {
        a = 1;
        //alert(a);
    } else if ($("#radiobtn3").is(':checked')) {
        a = 0;
        //alert(a);
    }


    if ($("#radiobtn4").is(':checked')) {
        b = 350;
        //alert(b);
    } else if ($("#radiobtn5").is(':checked')) {
        b = 450;
        //alert(b);
    } else if ($("#radiobtn6").is(':checked')) {
        b = 0;
        // alert(b);
    }

    if ($("#radiobtn7").is(':checked')) {
        c = 50;
        //alert(b);
    } else if ($("#radiobtn8").is(':checked')) {
        d = 20;
        //alert(b);
    } else if ($("#radiobtn9").is(':checked')) {
        e = 50;
        // alert(b);
    }


    if (a == 0) {
        price = 0;
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Contact Us For Pricing.";
        //alert(price);
    } else if (b == 0) {
        price = 0;
        // alert(price);
    } else {
        price = b;
        price = price + new Number(c) + new Number(d) + new Number(e);

        if (price != undefined) {
            price = "$" + price;
            //document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '$';
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = price;
        } else if (a == 0) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = "Contact Us For Pricing.";
        }
    }

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9VkEk/1/)

The math is still a little strange, so I'd check that.